# pandas.DataFrame.to_csv header formatting

Tags: pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I'm wondering if there is a method to change the string formatting in `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`.

In particular, I'd like to set each column header to something like `%20s` so that they are all evenly spaced out in the file. I read [this stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070923/writing-multiple-header-lines-in-pandas-dataframe-to-csv) but I was hoping to do it without writing the header beforehand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `to_csv` has a built in header formatting function, but you can always loop over the headers and fill them to the full length before printing. Something like

```
df.columns = [column_header.rjust(20, ' ') for column_header in df.columns]
```